# Getting Error while creating status in shotgun using python shotgun api

Tags: python, shotgun

I am using shotgun python api to create,delete,update in shotgun but i am getting error can anyone solve this ?

```
import shotgun_api3

shot = sg.create("Status",{"code":"Done1","name":"new1","icon":"Active"})

print shot
```

---

### Error

```
Fault: API create() Status.icon expected [Hash, NilClass] data type(s) but got 
String:"Active"
```

Answer (score 0):

proj_id = 1234
status_name = "New1"

status_entity = {
"project": {"type": "Project", "id": proj_id},
"code": status_name
}

_shot = sg.create("Status", status_entity)

Answer (score -1):

You try delete : ,"icon":"Active"

```
import shotgun_api3

shot = sg.create("Status",{"code":"Done1","name":"new1"})

print shot
```